# Publish HP ALM manual tests result into Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins-plugins, hp-alm

After many searches over the net, I couldn't find any option to publish manual test results from HP ALM (QC) into jenkins. For instance, we have some "Test Lab" running results, and we would like to see its status in the jenkins dashboard. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout [Agiletestware Bumblebee](https://www.agiletestware.com/bumblebee) plugin for Jenkins. It can trigger tests in HP ALM and then display results in the Jenkins dashboard.

Disclaimer: I'm developer of Bumblebee